# Webpack works perfectly for development, but production builds do not have any styles applied

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

My webpack configuration mostly works, but production builds have no css styling applied.

If I run webpack using this node script `webpack --mode development` then open the `./dist/index.html` file in my browser, the website works as expected and the content is styled correctly.

If I run webpack using this node script `webpack --mode production` then open the `./dist/index.html` file in my browser, the website content comes up but with no styling at all applied to the content.

The webpack dev server works perfectly with styled content, live update etc.

I modified my `webpack.config.js` to comment out the production specific settings, so that production and development builds use the exact same webpack config. I am having a hard time explaining why the development build works but the production build does not even with identical config. Any ideas on how to debug the issue?

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = (env, { mode }) => {
  var config = {
    entry: {
      app: './src/app.js',
      react: 'react',
    },
    devtool: 'none',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      compress: true,
      hot: true,
      port: 9000,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss', '.sass'],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'index.[hash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    },
    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendors',
            chunks: 'all',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        minify: false,
        template: require('html-webpack-template'),
        inject: true,
        title: 'Octopedia',
        favicon: './public/images/favicon/favicon.ico',
        appMountId: 'app',
        meta: [{ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' }],
        links: [{ href: '/site.webmanifest', rel: 'manifest' }],
        appMountHtmlSnippet: '<div class="app-spinner"></div>',
        headHtmlSnippet:
          '<style>div.app-spinner{position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;border:16px solid #f3f3f3;border-top:16px solid #3498db;border-radius:50%;width:120px;height:120px;margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;z-index:1;animation:spin 2s linear infinite;}@keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0deg);}100%{transform:rotate(360deg);}}</style >',
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: 'public' }],
      }),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  // if (mode === 'development') {
    config.mode = 'development';
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(sass|scss|css)/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    });
  // } else {
  //   config.mode = 'production';
  //   config.devtool = 'none';
  //   config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'index.css' }));
  //   config.module.rules.push({
  //     test: /\.(sass|scss|css)/,
  //     exclude: /node_modules/,
  //     use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  //   });
  // }

  return config;
};
```

The output from webpack in development mode looks like this:

```
                                    Asset       Size   Chunks                         Chunk Names
              app.6335bee170373d18f82e.js   39.8 KiB      app  [emitted] [immutable]  app
                              favicon.ico     15 KiB           [emitted]              
                         images/.DS_Store      6 KiB           [emitted]              
                 images/favicon/.DS_Store      6 KiB           [emitted]              
images/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png    8.1 KiB           [emitted]              
images/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png   23.3 KiB           [emitted]              
      images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png   7.25 KiB           [emitted]              
         images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png  534 bytes           [emitted]              
         images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png   1.06 KiB           [emitted]              
               images/favicon/favicon.ico     15 KiB           [emitted]              
            index.87da9b99395c61fa6b02.js   33.4 KiB  runtime  [emitted] [immutable]  runtime
                               index.html   1.04 KiB           [emitted]              
            react.a0fc75f932f5dd9cdda1.js  133 bytes    react  [emitted] [immutable]  react
                         site.webmanifest  447 bytes           [emitted]              
          vendors.404f5d4ed29b35b04b91.js   2.41 MiB  vendors  [emitted] [immutable]  vendors
Entrypoint app = index.87da9b99395c61fa6b02.js vendors.404f5d4ed29b35b04b91.js app.6335bee170373d18f82e.js
Entrypoint react = index.87da9b99395c61fa6b02.js vendors.404f5d4ed29b35b04b91.js react.a0fc75f932f5dd9cdda1.js
```

The output from webpack in production mode loolks like this:

```
                                    Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
              app.170943a8008bc467199f.js   2.77 KiB       2  [emitted] [immutable]         app
                              favicon.ico     15 KiB          [emitted]                     
                         images/.DS_Store      6 KiB          [emitted]                     
                 images/favicon/.DS_Store      6 KiB          [emitted]                     
images/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png    8.1 KiB          [emitted]                     
images/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png   23.3 KiB          [emitted]                     
      images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png   7.25 KiB          [emitted]                     
         images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png  534 bytes          [emitted]                     
         images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png   1.06 KiB          [emitted]                     
               images/favicon/favicon.ico     15 KiB          [emitted]                     
            index.a162f7e38dd204127c0f.js   9.03 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]         runtime
                               index.html   1.04 KiB          [emitted]                     
            react.f87e0cf2654ac4f74576.js   71 bytes       3  [emitted] [immutable]         react
                         site.webmanifest  447 bytes          [emitted]                     
          vendors.dd9d4a26464d8d880c74.js    352 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors
```

Comment: I just discovered that I can do 'webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production --profile --json > compilation-stats.json'. The generated compilation-stats.json contains no errors, and many references to scss files. Nothing jumps out.

Comment: From the reading I did today, I think this could possibly be to do with tree shaking and module side effects. Because nothing directly references anything inside the css, it's possible that webpack is removing it as an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of banging my head against a documentation brick wall, I finally tracked down the problem. I consider this to be a bug in webpack but others may disagree.

The issue comes about because in 'production' mode webpack performs optimizations that remove unreferenced code. This is a good thing of course, but it does not distinguish between javascript and other types of files, which to me is a bug.

The end result is that because none of my Javascript references anything exported from the css (how could it, css doesn't have ES6 import/export mechanism) the webpack tree shaker discards all of the css from the production build.

The solution is very simple but very hard to find. In your `package.json` file you need to add:

```
  "sideEffects": ["*.css", "*.scss", "*.sass"],
```

Which tells webpack that it cannot prune these modules from the tree, because just loading the module is enough to make the module provide functionality without anything in the module being referenced by the application.

It has taken three days of experimenting and reading docs and stackoverflow articles to track down this simple 1 line change. I hope this answer can save someone else from spending the same time.

Comment: Please post a Github repo when you can because I think you're still going to run into issues when moving it into production.

Comment: The `./dist` folder now contains exactly what I want. What problems do you anticipate having in production?

Comment: If you're outputting in `--mode development` then you're using unoptimized assets in production. If you're preventing tree shaking in production (using `sideEffects` for CSS), then without a bundler handing the CSS imports, it'll fail to load your components/assets. Common practice is to separate CSS imports from the JS so that they can be imported separately (CSS in the DOM's `head` and JS in the DOM's `body`). If you want to bundle them as a whole, then I'd suggest a `CSS-in-JSS` solution (like `@emotion`, `styled-components`, or `styled-jsx`)

Comment: Another reason to separate the CSS from JS would be if you wanted to utilize a CDN or create a NPM UI library. Instead of forcing a developer to use a bundler, they can simply import the compiled JS and the CSS separately. This way, they aren't locked into `webpack/gulp/rollup` nor would they need `css-loader/style-loader/sass` etc to handle uncompiled style-sheets.

Comment: I am not using `--mode development` for production builds, you misunderstood my comment. What I said was that I tried `--mode development` as an experiment, and it was the result of this experiment that eventually led me to the solution. Nobody in their right mind would deploy a development build to production.

Comment: I absolutely want to separate the CSS. Now that I have webpack actually including css in the output I can work on the rest of my configuration. Thank you so much for helping me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the same config, you'll need to condtionally add [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/):

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const inDevelopment = NODE_ENV === "development";

module.exports = {
  ...options,
  module: {
    rules: [
        ...rules,
        {
          test: /\.(scss|css)/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
                 inDevelopment ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                 'css-loader', 
                 'sass-loader'
               ],
        },
     ],
   },
   plugins: [
     ...plugins,
     !inDevelopment && new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "bundle.min.css" }),
   ].filter(Boolean)
}
```

In short, if you're in development it'll use `style-loader`. When you're in production, you'll use `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` with the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` plugin. The above assumes you'll want to bundle into a single css file. If you want to code-split it, then you'll need to add [optimization.splitChunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks) and update the plugin for [chunking](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/config/plugins.js#L103-L106).

Comment: I have been wrestling this issue all day, and tried many things - including the MiniCssExtractPlugin. Your example defined a filename for the plugin, which I didn't try before, so I tried again, but it makes no difference. Still no css file written to the output and no css links inserted in the html template.

Comment: Here's a [repo](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/webpack-starter) you can use as a reference. You can clone it and run it locally if you wish. Focus on the `config` folder and the `webpack.config.js` file. I divided the config up to make it easier to read and included a ton of notes.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will check it out this afternoon. I also updated my question with my latest code and findings. Specifically if I build with `--mode development` then the contents of the `./dist` folder work as expected so this is not a dev server difference like I first thought.

Comment: Dev-server should only be used for development: `"dev": "webpack-dev-server"`. When building for production, you should only be using webpack: `"build": "webpack -p"` (`-p` tells webpack it's building for production).

Comment: Thanks Matt, I know that already, and do only use dev server for development. To help with narrowing down the issue I tried doing a normal build (not dev server) with `--mode development` and the output in `./dist` folder now works.

Comment: You shouldn't need to output files in development. Dev-server should write them to memory and then `webpack` should output files to disk for production. Using `--mode development` with `webpack` means you're not outputting production files (for example, you're attempting to run a development build of React in production).

Comment: Matt I am upvoting your answer because it was helpful, and I got plenty of useful tips from the repo you shared, but the answer turned out to be that the webpack tree shaking algorithm is removing the css because nothing in these modules is referenced by the application.

Comment: Are you importing the stylesheets? Or are you sticking them in the `head` as `link`s?

Comment: The stylesheets are scss and they are imported into the js with an import statement. This is enough for webpack to include them in the list of modules, but the tree shaker subsequently removes them because nothing within the css is referenced by javascript. No tree shaking occurs in development, which is why the development build works and the production build does not.